# EF 6 ChangeTracker Eliminate Duplicate Entity Entries

Tags: entity-framework

I have ran into a scenario where in some instances, the DbContext ChangeTracker may have two entries that are the same, both marked with a State as "Added".

I put together a `FixState()` helper method which tracks the entities that are about to be Add/Updated etc.  Is there a way within this `FixState()` that I can tell the change tracker to no longer track a duplicate object?

I am using `entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;` which doesn't seem to work:

```
public void FixState()
{
    var changeTrackedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>();
    // In place list used to ensure the same entities don't get marked as added twice
    var list = new List<Int64>();

    foreach (var entry in changeTrackedEntities) {
        IObjectWithState stateInfo = entry.Entity;
        if (entry.Entity is INWatchEntityObject)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                Int64 sixtyFourBitValue 
                    = ((INWatchEntityObject)entry.Entity).Id | ((entry.Entity.GetType().GetHashCode()) << 32);

                if (!list.Contains(sixtyFourBitValue)) {
                    list.Add(sixtyFourBitValue);
                    entry.State = Utilities.ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
                }
                else {
                    // Duplicate object found, mark it as Unchanged.
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the object to be ignored by the context, you would need the object to be `Detached` not `Unchanged`, right? [See here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've tried the same same with Detached and still get the error of a duplicate PK being inserted.